# Export and Import a defined function in Python3.9

Tags: python, function, import, export

I have been attempting to define a python function in one script (lets call it script1.py) like so:

```
def fn1(): 
 print("Hello")
```

and then to import it into a separate python file in the same directory (lets call it script2.py) like this:

`from script1 import fn1`
or `import script1`

I've found lots of posts/answers supporting this process, but I continue to receive the error message that there is "No module named 'script1'". Most of the posts I've seen are from 3+ years ago, so perhaps the newer versions of python have terminated this option.

I appreciate any solutions!

Comment: So, where are your scripts located? Are they in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory/folder

Comment: Ok, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) might help.

Comment: Have you tried with `from .script1 import fn1`

Comment: @BradFigueroa just gave it a go, received the error message "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two files are in the same folder, you can try adding a blank __init__.py file to your folder and using a relative import:

```
from .script1 import fn1
```

Adding the '.' before the module name ensures that your script is looking in the current directory.

To specify the parent directory, try:
`from {folder_name}.script1 import fn1`
where folder_name is parent directory

You can read more about relative imports in [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).

Comment: I've tried this, but received the error message "attempted relative import with no known parent package", do you gave any suggestions on how to specify the parent package?

Comment: I edited my comment, you can mark the directory as a module by creating a blank \_\_init\_\_.py file in the same folder

Comment: I have added the blank __init__.py file to the folder and am running the import in script2.py without any success, I appreciate the efforts, any other ideas?

Comment: @jros can you try with `from {folder_name}.script1 import fn1` where folder_name is parent directory

Comment: unfortunately not, I am however able to get the: import .script1 portion to work but importing the function is still not working

Comment: @BradFigueroa I figured out I had to reference the whole path for the project to get it to work: import project1.scripts.test.script1 (If you would add that to your answer or something suggesting that idea, I'll accept your answer and close the post) Thanks!